# How can I return a byte array (rather than an Object array) from a PowerShell function

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function that return a a byte array (`[Byte[]]`).

However, when I use the function and assign the returned value to a variable, the type of the variable is an array of objects (`[Object[]]`).

```
function make-byteArray() {
  [OutputType([Byte[]])]

   [byte[]] $byteArray = new-object byte[] 2
   $byteArray[0] = 0
   $byteArray[1] = 1

   write-host "type of byteArray: $($byteArray.GetType().FullName)"

   return $byteArray
}

$x = make-byteArray
write-host "type of x: $($x.GetType().FullName)"
```

I am puzzled why that is and would like to know what I can do to force the function to return a byte array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the [unary comma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#comma-operator-) `,` before the returned `$byteArray` like this:

```
return ,$byteArray
```

Return:

```
type of byteArray: System.Byte[]
type of x: System.Byte[]
```

This will wrap the returned array inside another, one-element array.
When an array is returned from a function, PowerShell 'unrolls' that and in this case, it unrolls the wrapper array, leaving the byte array inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Write-Output` Instead of return:

```
Write-Output $bytearray -NoEnumerate
```

Return statement always unpacks the return object so it gets a type of System.Object[]